# possibility of setting the Voice Over Cursor in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I am programming a text-based RPG for Voice-Over users on the iPhone.

I've got multiple UIViews added to my viewcontroller for different events.

I often remove and add them to my main View.

My Question is as follows: is it possible to update the VoiceOver Cursor to focus on the first Element on the View so the User doesn't has to check every Time if there has happened something new?

I figured out that this happens in a Navigationcontroller.

Is there a functionality to do this?

Answer (score 1):

By posting a `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification`, you inform VoiceOver that the layout of the screen has changed. You can also use `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` if you want to make a specific announcement.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);
```

Reference: [UIAccessibility Protocol Introduction, Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the VoiceOver cursor in iOS 4 or 5. I wish you could, it would solve so many issues.

I think this will be possible with iOS 6. See this answer for more info on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995385/1455770