# Force NSAccessibility Voiceover to read unfocused OS X textfield?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility, voiceover

I have a button, that when pressed, shows a "helper" window.

This window is shown, but not given keyboard focus, via `orderFrontRegardless`.

The window contains an `NSTextView` with helper text inside.

For vision-impaired users, I would like OS X's voiceover to immediately read the contents of this window's text view when it appears.

I am attempting to make VoiceOver read the text via:

```
NSAccessibilityPostNotification(textView, NSAccessibilityValueChangedNotification);
```

In my subclass of `NSTextView` I then override the accessibility method:

```
- (id)accessibilityAttributeValue:(NSString *)attribute
{
    //The notification calls this method for attributes:
    //AXRole: returns AXTextArea
    //AXSharedCharacterRange: returns range of the text view

    return [super accessibilityAttributeValue:attribute];
}
```

The notification causes it to query for `AXRole` (`NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute`) and `AXSharedCharacterRange` (`NSAccessibilitySharedCharacterRangeAttribute`).

The character range correctly returns the range of the text area.

However, at no point is `AXValue` (`NSAccessibilityValueAttribute`) requested. That is that I am expecting is required when wanting VoiceOver to read the textfield.

Why is the `NSAccessibilityValueChangedNotification` not requesting the TextView's `NSAccessibilityValueAttribute`? How do I make VoiceOver read the text area's text?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no way you can do it without setting the focus to the desired `NSTextView`.

I have found a solution using iOS that maybe can be implemented in this OSX application: [VoiceOver: force an accessibility element to be selected after a screen transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659881/voiceover-force-an-accessibility-element-to-be-selected-after-a-screen-transiti)

> In iOS you can pass in an accessibility element when posting a
>   `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` or
>   `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` as the second argument to
>   `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` and VoiceOver will focus on that
>   element.

Maybe you can use a similar approach with `NSAccessibility` framework with `NSAccessibilityPostNotification`

Answer (score 1):

You can now do it using `NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification`.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityannouncementrequestednotification?language=objc.

Answer (score 0):

Override

```
-(NSArray *)accessibilityAttributeNames
{
    NSMutableArray *attributeNames = [[super accessibilityAttributeNames] mutableCopy];
    [attributeNames addObject:NSAccessibilityValueAttribute];
    return attributeNames;
}
```

Have you tried NSLog into there to find out if NSAccessibilityValueAttribute is an attribute at all?