# Disable VoiceOver on UIButton/UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell Selection

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

With VoiceOver switched-on, when focus comes on a `UIButton`/`UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell`, VoiceOver reads it's accessibility label once.

Then as soon as user double taps to select that `UIButton`/`UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell`, VoiceOver reads the same accessibility label again besides performing action (navigation etc) on `UIButton`/`UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell` selection.

I've searched a lot but not able to find a way to stop/disable VoiceOver reading accessibility label on `UIButton`/`UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell` selection.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. I handled it by forced selection of another accessibility element. For example, after making selection from TableView/CollectionView, I'm supposed to navigate to new UI. What I'm doing is that I forcefully select left bar button item of navigation bar of new UI right after navigation is completed. Selection is made using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification`. This way, it starts reading newly selected item. Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659881/voiceover-force-an-accessibility-element-to-be-selected-after-a-screen-transiti) for selection

Comment: @XLE_22 I had posted this question almost three years before your answer was posted so I never tried your solution but appreciate your contribution. I had already used a workaround mentioned right above your recent message that has received 2 upvotes as well, so apparently that helped others too. However I don't see any upvote on your answer from anyone else as well.

Comment: Thanks Maverick for your return and your validated answer.  My question only dealt with the fact that some solutions were found out for your problem with no validation... whatever it's mine or not. The goal is to info others that your initial question has a validated answer. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This worked for me at the time I had asked this question (a workaround, not proper solution).

I handled it by forced selection of another accessibility element. For example, after making selection from TableView/CollectionView, I'm supposed to navigate to new UI. What I'm doing is that I forcefully select left bar button item of navigation bar of new UI right after navigation is completed. Selection is made using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification`. This way, it starts reading newly selected item. Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995385/3659227) for selection

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how to stop the VoiceOver accessibility reading for the `UIButton` and the `UITableViewCell` elements.

**UIBUTTON** : just create your own button class and override the [`accessibilityActivate`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DefaultActivation) method.

```
class BoutonLabelDoubleTap: UIButton {

    override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
        accessibilityLabel = ""
        return true
    }
}
```

**UITABLEVIEWCELL** : two steps to be followed.

- Create a custom `UIAccessibilityElement` overriding the [`accessibilityActivate`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DefaultActivation) method.

  ```
  class TableViewCellLabelDoubleTap: UIAccessibilityElement {

      override init(accessibilityContainer container: Any) {
          super.init(accessibilityContainer: container)
      }

      override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
          get { return UIAccessibilityTraitNone }
          set {   }
      }

      override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
          accessibilityLabel = ""
          return true
      }
  }
  ```
- Use the previous created class to implement your table view cells in the view controller.

  ```
  class TestButtonTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

      @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
      @IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          myTableView.delegate = self as UITableViewDelegate
          myTableView.dataSource = self as UITableViewDataSource
      }

      func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return 1
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                     numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return 2
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                     cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let zeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myPersoCell",
                                                     for: indexPath)

          zeCell.accessibilityElements = nil
          var elements = [UIAccessibilityElement]()

          let a11yEltCell = TableViewCellLabelDoubleTap(accessibilityContainer: zeCell)
          a11yEltCell.accessibilityLabel = "cell number " + String(indexPath.row)
          a11yEltCell.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                                  y: 0,
                                                                  width: zeCell.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                                                  height: zeCell.contentView.frame.size.height)
          elements.append(a11yEltCell)
          zeCell.accessibilityElements = elements

          return zeCell
      }
  }
  ```

I haven't tried for a `UICollectionViewCell` but it should be the same rationale as the `UITableViewCell`'s.

Following these code snippets, **you're now able to decide if VoiceOver should stop reading out the desired elements labels when selected**.

Comment: How can we stop the voice over "1 of 10", "2 of 10" etc. Facing an issue in UIPickerView where it always says "1 of 10" whenever we swipe to any elment

Comment: @Nishchith I'm not sure you listen "1 over x" for each cell in this scrollable view example I provided, don't you? (more than 2 years now ⏳) I didn't make any test with a picker view and the only answer I provided is https://stackoverflow.com/a/61018428/3825084, sorry.

Comment: Sure thanks. I am facing this issue of the current index not voicing out properly. It always says "1 of total" when I swipe. Do you have any idea how we can completely disable the voice over only when the picker swipe happens?
On setting my own accessibilityLabel. It voices out accessibility label text and then the default one as well. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183280/uipickerview-accessibility-voiceover-issue

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

What worked for me was setting `myElementIWantSilent.accessibilityTraits = .none`

EDIT: I should note that these are also present:

```
viewContainingSilentElement.isAccessibilityElement = true
viewContainingSilentElement.accessibilityTraits = .image
viewContainingSilentElement.accessibilityLabel = "some text i want read aloud"
```

iPhone 8
iOS 14.5.1
XCode 12.5